# Allow HTML comments in DomPurify

Tags: javascript, html, sanitization, dompurify

I would like to use DOMPurify to sanitise some HTML content, but I'd like to preserve the HTML comments. Is that possible?

You can see what it does in [this example](https://cure53.de/purify) - if you enter markup with a comment the comment is stripped out.

DOMPurify seems very configurable, but the [docs](https://cure53.de/purify) don't mention what term to use to specify HTML comment as an allowed tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMPurify` doesn't have any hooks or configuration to allow comments in html string. You can do one this just replace the `<!--` and `-->` to any custom attribute and provide configuration to allow `ADD_TAGS: ['comment']` it.

```
var dirty = "<!-- I am ready now, click one of the buttons! -->ac <script>in script<\/script> <b>hello</b>";
dirty = dirty.replace(/(<!--)/g,'<comment>').replace(/(-->)/g,'</comment>');
var config = { ALLOWED_TAGS: ['b'],ADD_TAGS: ['comment']};
var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, config);
clean = clean.replace(/(<comment>)/g,'<!--').replace(/(<\/comment>)/g,'-->');
console.log("clean => ",clean);
```

jsFiddle demo - http://jsfiddle.net/4j6c28ve/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question, there's a much better solution for this, that is not [messing around with regex in markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) (spoiler alert: don't!):

```js
var dirty = "<!-- I am ready now, click one of the buttons! -->ac <script>in script<\/script> <b>hello</b>";
var config = { ADD_TAGS: ['#comment'], FORCE_BODY: true };
var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, config);
console.log("clean => ",clean);
// >>> clean => <!-- I am ready now, click one of the buttons! -->ac  <b>hello</b>
```

Comment: I like this solution better than the accepted answer, except it isn't working for me with DOMPurify 2.3.6.   It's encoding the opening < of the comment as \x3C so that <!--hello--> is sanitized to \x3C!--hello-->